# Extract data from a table object using autolisp

Tags: lisp, cell, autocad, autolisp

I want to extract certain information from the comparison of the information stored in a drawing-table or table object, as you prefer to call it, if the comparison succeeds then store the related values into variables. I am new to Visual lisp or Auto Lisp. So please can you help me with that issue and explain me step by step please.

[image: Example of table]

So for example, if my table have in the first column **D1** I want to store the information in the next three columns next to it but in the same row.

[image]

So in this example it would be **132156**, **432** y **11** the numbers to be stored in three different variables or an array. Please help me and explain me step by step the possible solutions, I am really new to Lisp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first You need to get table. You can ask user to select one, for example like this:

```
(setq table (vlax-ename->vla-object (car (entsel ))) )
```

You should remember to catch error if user wouldn't like to select .
Also You should check if user select table not some other enity. but now let's imagine that user select table
so now You may try this

```
(setq columns (vlax-get-property table 'Columns))
(setq rows (vlax-get-property table 'rows))

(setq row 1 )   ; 0 is header
(repeat rows
    (setq vals nil)
    (setq column 0)
    (setq txtval (vlax-invoke-method table 'GetText row column ))
        ; now we have value from first cell in row.
        ; and now You can go at least two ways. 
        ; 1 check value and make Your analyse, read values from other columns or anything You need
        ; 2 build array of all values from all cells and after that analyse only array of texts (remove dependency from object table)
        ; for this sample I choose 1 way.
    (if (= txtval "D1") (progn          
        (repeat 3 ; because You "want to store the information in the next three columns"
            (setq column (1+ column))
            (setq vals ( append vals (list (vlax-invoke-method table 'GetText row column ))))
        )
    ))
    (if (not (null vals )) (progn
        (setq arrayOfVals (append arrayOfVals (list vals)))
    ))
    (setq row (1+ row ))
)

(print arrayOfVals)
```